# CDialog::Create () method is failing on vista windows 7 32 bit PC

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog, richedit-control

> CDialog::Create() is failing on Win7 32 bit PC because dialog have
>   Richedit control.
>
> Once i remove that control from dialog,It got created but i need
>   Richedit control.
>
> Why CDialog::Create() is fails when i use Richedit control ? Also i
>   called "**AfxInitRichEdit2()**"

Comment: Check what GetLastError returnes

Comment: GetLastError returns 0.

Comment: Where is it failing in the MFC code.

Comment: @rrirower create API is failing.

Comment: @user2778665 And, as was asked earlier, what does that function return for an error code?

Comment: CDialog dlg ;
BOOL res = dlg.create ( CDialog::IDD , PWnd ) ;
here res is false and error code is zero .

Comment: @user2778665 Your usage of AfxInitRichEdit2 implies you are using version 2.0 or 3.0 of the rich edit control.  Is that correct?

Comment: I think 2.0 because in .rc file it shows "RichEdit20A" this.Am I correct?

Comment: @user2778665 I would assume that is correct.  Next question...did you define a member variable for the control, and, if so, did you cut and paste, or, use the ClassWizard to define the control?  Have you tried to step through the dialog creation code to determine the cause of the false return?

Comment: See this link:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/desktop/ms645452(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: I think in that PC control is not registered. Can some one tell what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

RichEdit might also need OLE initialization: AfxOleInit()

Comment: No, It's not working! It's happening only in that PC.